# Which API takes higher priority over registerColumnType and registerHibernateType?

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, dialect

I read usage of these to apis as

> registerHibernateType :used to define a default type that hibernate
>   supports.
>
> registerColumnType : used to register a type for the given type code
>   and maximum column length. In other words, registerColumnType is more
>   detaild to define a sql-type.

So,If i declare below stagements in my MSSQL dialect

```
registerColumnType(Types.NCHAR,1, "nchar(1)");
registerColumnType(Types.NCHAR, "string");
registerHibernateType(Types.NCHAR,1, StandardBasicTypes.CHARACTER.getName());
registerHibernateType(Types.NCHAR, StandardBasicTypes.STRING.getName());
```

Which takes higher priority among these type in MSSQL ?

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problem in my dialect:

```
registerColumnType(Types.VARCHAR, "nvarchar(MAX)");
registerColumnType(Types.VARCHAR, 4000, "nvarchar($l)");
```

The first line represents the default mapping, the second line defines the maximum length for your "weighted" mapping. The process is as follows:

1. Hibernate tries to find all weighted mappings for your type.
2. If found any weighted mapping for your type - hibernate tries to find a mapping with max capacity <= size (in my case 4000 <= size from your column definition).
3. If found any weighted mapping corresponding to your size - replaces size with $l argument ($l for lenght, $s for scale, $p for precision).
4. If no weighted mapping found (there was no weighted registration for that typeCode or There was no weighting whose max capacity was big enough to contain size) - returns default mapping (also tries to replace).